# is there an easier way to write this code pattern?

Tags: python

I am building an evaluator and often encounters this code pattern. Is there a simpler (shorter, more Pythonic, etc) way to write this? It should either return None if the list of operands is empty, the first operand if there is only one to process, and actually create an `Add` node by calling a function otherwise.

```
# l contains a list of operands to process
if not l: ans = None
elif len(l) == 1: ans = l[0]   
else: ans = createAddNode(*l)  # returns Add(a, b, c, ...)

return ans
```

I find myself repeating this code pattern for various operations like subtract, multiply, divide, etc

Comment: Please provide context for this code. I have no idea how to begin making a suggestion without knowing what its specification is. How do you define simpler, exactly? Even then, the question may be opinion-based. Thanks for clarifying. All that said, I'd suggest putting blocks on new lines for readability.

Comment: What uses `ans`? It's usually simpler to deal with singleton lists than to mess around "simplifying" things by using scalar values instead of singleton lists.

Comment: [Sourcery](https://sourcery.ai/) provides great help with refactoring Python code.

Comment: Are you aware of `reduce`? It doesn't do *exactly* what you're asking for, but I think it does what you *want*.

Answer (score 0):

Since in python you do not have to specify the return type of a function, you can omit the first line.

```
if l:
   ans = l[0] if len(l) == 1 else createAddNode(*l)
   return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to answer this without context but I will try and give some suggestions

```
def test(l):
    # l contains a list of operands to process
    if not l: 
        ans = None
    elif len(l) == 1: 
        ans = l[0]   
    else: 
        ans = createAddNode(*l)  # returns Add(a, b, c, ...)
    
    return ans
```

at the very least you should have these if statements on separate lines for readability.

```
if not l: 
    ans = None
```

This statement is rather redundant as you are already evaluating whatever is stored in the collection "l" to empty

```
elif len(l) == 1: 
    ans = l[0]
```

this suggestion depends on what "createAddNode" does but once again this seems rather redundant. I would find a way to evaluate this expression inside "createAddNode".

```
def test(l):
    # l contains a list of operands to process
    if l: 
        return createAddNode(*l)  # returns Add(a, b, c, ...)
```

this would be my final function assuming you refactor createAddNode to handle the base case where length is one. This will return None if l is empty

Just as a side note I don't see a point in unpacking a variable amount of arguments in your "createAddNode" function. Odds are you can probably just do this with a for loop, but this obviously depends on what you are trying to unpack.